# In Azure IOT Device Portal, how to change data field names?

Tags: node.js, azure, iot

The sample comes with temperature and humidity as data fields. Although I replaced the data with my own different fields, the names remain the same.

I cannot find a simple rename column option. How do I change it?

Comment: Which sample? Where are the data fields located? Would you mind providing more detailed information?

Comment: Remote monitoring sample. The fields are located in the devices and rules tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow these steps:

1. In the code, you need change the name in `DeviceRuleDataFields` class, for example, I changed "Humidity" to "HumidityEdit", look at this picture:
   [image]
2. In IoT Device Portal Web page, you need select the rule you want to change, and you will see "Rule Properties" and "Edit" button in the right region, like this:
   [image]
3. Press the "Edit" button and you enter the rule edit page, in the "DATA FIELD" select the "HumidityEdit", like this:
   [image]
4. Save the change of the rule and you will get the changed data field name of the rule, look at this picture:
   [image]

Comment: I am using the nodejs API instead of C#. I am sure I have already tried the nodejs equivalent of what you just said. I am no longer planning to use Azure IOT but I will accept the answer for the reference of others.